# assign timestamp in jpa annotation

Tags: jpa, ejb

is there a way to automatically assing a timestamp value in a Date variable on a enity EJB?

here is how my enity looks like.

```
package com.jr.entities;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;

public class TransactionDAO {

    private String uid;

    private ProductDAO product;

    @Column(name="date")
    private Date date;

    private String customerId;

}
```

i could not find any examples how this is done or does this have to be done programatically?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean, have an initial value for new objects?

Just initialize it in the object's constructor, or in the field def.

Comment: i want to automaticallly record and store the date and time i.e a timestamp as soon as the record is added to the table

Comment: im guessing there is no way to do that? maybe i will use a TRIGGER instead